# How to get the expression string of a Regex object in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I want to get the regular expression of the `r` object in `foo`, i.e: "A.B"
Any idea?

```
//C++ 11 or higher,  Now I have an object of regex:
std::regex reg = std::regex("A.B");

//some other function with reg as input
void foo(regex r)
{
    string ab = ???;
}
```

Comment: Btw, there are several strings which result in same regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/basic_regex/ the answer is you can't; there is no function that provides that.

The solution, if you need that functionality, is to put it in a tuple/pair/custom struct and move them around together.

Comment: cplusplus.com is not known for its accuracy, rather the opposite. Prefer [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex).